# Joomla loads only certain parts of css template

Tags: css, templates, joomla

I am working on a Joomla! template and I have my index and my template.css

When I leave all the design in css it appears to load only those parts concerning css classes and doesnt do anything else, so eventually I have to write everything else into de index.php which is silly because Im not supposed to.

For instance this is the code I want for my index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" >  
<head>  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/posgradostemplate/css/template.css" type="text/css" /> 
<jdoc:include type="head" />  
</head>  
<body>  
<div id="wrapper">  
    <div id="content">  
      <div class="mainmenu"> 
          <jdoc:include type="modules" name="mainmenu" />          
      </div>  
  </div>  
</div>  
</body>  
</html>
```

But wrapper and content do not behave as expected and no background is shown. This is my css file:

```
html {

/* IE10 Consumer Preview */ 
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #E6E6E6 0%, #858585 100%);

/* Mozilla Firefox */ 
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #E6E6E6 0%, #858585 100%);

/* Opera */ 
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #E6E6E6 0%, #858585 100%);

/* Webkit (Safari/Chrome 10) */ 
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #E6E6E6), color-stop(1, #858585));

/* Webkit (Chrome 11+) */ 
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #E6E6E6 0%, #858585 100%);

/* W3C Markup, IE10 Release Preview */ 
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #E6E6E6 0%, #858585 100%);
 margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}


.mainmenu ul {
    font-family: Arial, Verdana;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.mainmenu ul li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
.mainmenu li ul {
    display: none;
}
.mainmenu ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-top: 1px solid #000000;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
    background: #000000;
    margin-left: 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.mainmenu li:hover li a:hover {
    background: #FFFF00;
    color: #FF0000;
}
.mainmenu ul li a:hover {
    background: #000000;
    color: #FFFF00;
}
.mainmenu li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute; 
}
.mainmenu li:hover li {
    background: #FFFF00;
    float: none;
    font-size: 11px;
    color : #000000;
}
.mainmenu li:hover a { 
    background:  #FFFF00;
    color : #000000;
}


#wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

#content{
    display: inline-block;

}
```

Everything other than mainmenu is not working as the css tells it to. I am thinking that it is not being loaded properly, I want it to be loaded eagerly, so that everything is had in mind. Right now it only works if I add the css code in the index and it should not be that way. Suggestions?

Comment: Have you installed Firebug or a similar tool to see what css is being loaded?
Usually for me css not loading means I have a typo in the file right where the loading stops. Also be careful about hidden characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the CSS file using the following:

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addStyleSheet(JURI::root() . "templates/posgradostemplate/css/template.css");
```